# Remove border bottom from single table cell

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to remove the border between the cell containing paper and the row that contains the menu table.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0zf2wq5b/)**

When I inspect the elements, I cannot find where the border is coming from.  The containing `td` and `tr` both show a bottom-border of none, and the `tr`, `td`, `table`, `tbody`, and `tr` containing the menu show a border-top of none.

It would be helpful if someone can show where the border between the cell containing paper and the `tr` containing the menu is coming from, and how to get rid of it

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing: 0">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom: 2px solid gray">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="border-left: 2px solid gray; border-top: 2px solid gray; border-right:2px solid gray" id="PaperInfoTab"><a onclick="setTabs('Paper')" >Paper</a></td>
        <td style="border-left: 2px solid gray; border-top: 2px solid gray; border-right:2px solid gray" id="EDIInfoTab"><a onclick="setTabs('EDI')">EDI</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-top:none">
        <td colspan="3" style="border-left: 2px solid gray; border-bottom: 2px solid gray; border-right:2px solid gray; border-top: none">
            <table style="border-top: none">
                <tbody style="border-top:none">
                    <tr style="border-top: none">
                        <td style="color: blue; border-top:none">Dashboard</td>
                        <td style="border-left: 2px solid gray; border-top: none"><a href="/EdiClaim/Index" target="_blank" style="color: gray">Edi Claims</a> </td>
                        <td style="border-left: 2px solid gray; border-top: none"><a href="/PaperClaim/Index" target="_blank" style="color: gray">Paper Claims</a> </td>
                        <td style="border-left: 2px solid gray; border-top: none"><a href="/Dashboard/Details" target="_blank" style="color: gray">Details</a></td>
                        <td style="border-left: 2px solid gray; border-top: none"><a href="/Utilities/Index" target="_blank" style="color: gray">Utilities</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's what's going on in setTabs.

```
function setTabs(activetab)
{
    if (activetab == 'Paper') {
        $("#PaperInfoTab").css({ 'color': 'blue','border-bottom': 'none'  });
        $("#EDIInfoTab").css({ 'color': "black", 'border-bottom': '2px solid gray' });
        $("#PaperInfo").css({ 'color': 'blue', 'visibility': 'visible'});
        $("#EdiInfo").css({ 'visibility': 'hidden', });
        $("#EdiInfo").hide();
        $("#PaperInfo").show();
    }
    if (activetab == 'EDI') {
        $("#PaperInfoTab").css({ 'color': 'black', 'border-bottom': '2px solid gray' });
        $("#EDIInfoTab").css({ 'color': "blue", 'border-bottom': 'none' });
        $("#EdiInfo").css({ 'color': 'blue', 'visibility': 'visible'});
        $("#PaperInfo").css({ 'visibility': 'hidden'});
        $("#EdiInfo").show();
        $("#PaperInfo").hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Yes.  it shows the same behavior in JSFiddle

Comment: @DanHass I think he was requesting that you edit your question and add the problem in a jsFiddle.

Comment: @DanHass You need to put something (your attempts) out there by yourselves (jsfiddle) before asking us to look into it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0zf2wq5b/

Comment: Works for me. You forgot to include jQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/0zf2wq5b/1/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

http://jsfiddle.net/y0bpgd8t/1/

I removed borders from different  elements See code below:

```
<table style="border-collapse:collapse; border-spacing: 0">
    <tr>
        <td style="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="" id="PaperInfoTab"><a onclick="setTabs('Paper')" >Paper</a></td>
        <td style="" id="EDIInfoTab"><a onclick="setTabs('EDI')">EDI</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border-top:none">
        <td colspan="3" style="">
            <table style="border-top: none">
                <tbody style="border-top:none">
                    <tr style="border-top: none">
                        <td style="color: blue; border-top:none">Dashboard</td>
                        <td style="border-left: 2px solid gray; border-top: none"><a href="/EdiClaim/Index" target="_blank" style="color: gray">Edi Claims</a> </td>
                        <td style="border-left: 2px solid gray; border-top: none"><a href="/PaperClaim/Index" target="_blank" style="color: gray">Paper Claims</a> </td>
                        <td style="border-left: 2px solid gray; border-top: none"><a href="/Dashboard/Details" target="_blank" style="color: gray">Details</a></td>
                        <td style="border-left: 2px solid gray; border-top: none"><a href="/Utilities/Index" target="_blank" style="color: gray">Utilities</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No.  I want a border that goes over the top and sides of the tabs.  And the tab that isn't active should have a bottom-border between it and the menu, but the active tab shouldn't have a bottom-border between it and the menu.  And the menu should have the same border all the way around except for the region between it and the active tab.

Comment: You mean besides setting every possible border manually?  And then stepping through ever single element to see that the code shows they are all set the way they are supposed to be?  (As I explained in my question...)

Comment: If you must use tables, did you try doing <table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0> ?